# How to add the collapsible button for start and stop in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page in that page I have created one button for start or stop (which is toggle) But it is not working properly.

**.component.ts**

```
toggleCollapse(jammer) {
    this.jammer.isCollapsed ? 'START' : 'STOP'
    this.jammer.isCollapsed ? 'START' : 'STOP'
}
```

**.component.html**

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-warning"
    (click)="toggleCollapse()">START</button>
```

But it is not working properly can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working properly"

Comment: It is not toggling between start and stop for click function (what I have mentioned in the html)

Comment: That is because you never *assign* the value to anything

Comment: Can you please add whatever I made the mistakes in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.component.ts

```
public isCollapsed = false;

toggleCollapse() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed
}
```

.component.html

```
     <button
        type="button"
        [ngClass]="isCollapsed ? 'btn btn-warning' : 'btn btn-success'"
        (click)="toggleCollapse()">
        <span *ngIf="isCollapsed"> Stop <span>
        <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed"> Start <span>
    </button>
```

Note : You can change the boolean if you want

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the label of the button to either be START or STOP?

```
isCollapsed: boolean = true;

toggleCollapse() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
}
```

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-warning"
    (click)="toggleCollapse()">{{isCollapsed? 'START' : 'STOP'}}</button>
```